# I'm trying to result one row from 3 (or more) different rows with only one image to display

Tags: php, sql, select, distinct

I'm trying to result one row from 3 (or more) different rows with only one image to display and IsOriginal = 1 based on the same barcode (or id).

Here is my table for example:

Products

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  | IsOriginal |    Name    |    Brcode    |    Image    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     0      |   Pasta    |  123456789   |  pasta1.jpg |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     0      |   Pasta    |  123456789   |  pasta2.jpg |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     1      |   Pasta    |      1       |     NULL    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I"m trying to result this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  | IsOriginal |    Name    |    Brcode    |    Image    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     1      |   Pasta    |      1       |  pasta1.jpg |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    p1.id, 
    p1.IsOriginal, 
    p1.Name, 
    p1.Brcode, 
    p2.Image as Image
FROM Products p1
join Products p2
on p1.id = p2.id
where p1.IsOriginal = 1
```

and p2.Image is not null

Comment: . . Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select p.*,
       (select p2.image
        from products p2
        where p2.id = p.id and p2.image is not null
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as imputed_image
from products p
where isOriginal = 1;
```

This returns an arbitrary matching image for the same id.

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: add a TOP(1) in the subquery; ...select TOP(1) p2.image from products p2...

Comment: In addition to MrTex comment, you can also add an ORDER BY clause to the subquery, if you want to control which image gets selected